# Does anyone know why when I run my code it wont display the label, I'm new to this whole oop thing

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class gui():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.homePage()
```

> Don't think I need to pass self into homePage but tried to see if that would make it work

```
    def homePage(self):
        label = Label(self.window,text='Hello')
        label.pack()
```

> Program will still run the window but without packing the label

```
def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Morse Code Converter')
    window.geometry('600x600')
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code, just copy and paste it.

Comment: You have not created instance of `gui`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you; but the code you wrote is wrong in many ways. It defies the functionality of classes built in python. Also, the variables used in the class called `self.window` is defined as null or `None`. Here is a simple example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *

class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
       
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app = MainApplication()
    app.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
If you want to use some type of "sub-packages", you can start with this `tk.Label(self, text="{/n}").pack()`. Or you can do it manually by importing the needed packages by `from tkinter import Label`

Comment: Thanks for this information, I'm not the best at coding and fail to understand what this means for my code. Are you saying not to import the whole tkinter library bur rather just the modules I need? Also How does this stop the label from displaying in the tkinter window?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `gui` class.  Also you need to save the `window` argument as an instance variable in order to use it inside `homepage()`.

```py
from tkinter import *

class gui():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window  # save window argument for later use
        self.homePage()

    def homePage(self):
        label = Label(self.window, text='Hello')
        label.pack()

def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Morse Code Converter')
    window.geometry('600x600')
    app = gui(window) # create an instance of gui class
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: re-wrote to improve cleaner code.

Easier way put `Label` widget inside  `def __init__()` function.

- And use `label.config` in `homePage()` function.
- Add `app = gui(window)` below `mainloop()`

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class gui():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.label = tk.Label(window)
        self.label.pack() 
        self.homePage(window)
         
          
    def homePage(self, window):
        self.label.config(text='Hello')
         

def main():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title('Morse Code Converter')
    window.geometry('600x600')
    app = gui(window)
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

[image]